# How to solve dependencies inclusion order issues?

Tags: c++, xlib

I am trying to recompile a project that has two dependencies : Qt and X11.

X11 define the following symbols in the global namespace :

```
// Xlib.h
#define Bool int
#define Status int
#define True 1
#define False 0

// X.h
#define None 0L
```

However, those symbols (and maybe more) are also used in Qt (in enums, for instance).  As we can see in qcoreevent.h :

```
enum Type {
    /*
      If you get a strange compiler error on the line with None,
      it's probably because you're also including X11 headers,
      which #define the symbol None. Put the X11 includes after
      the Qt includes to solve this problem.
    */
    None = 0,    
 ...
```

The solution provided by Qt is simple : include X11 at last. But I am having trouble with the following situation :

File1.hpp

```
#include <SomeQtHeader.h>
#include <SomeX11Header.h> // Ok, X11 is included after Qt
... some classes ...
```

File2.hpp

```
#include <SomeOtherQtHeader.h>
#include <SomeX11Header.h> // Ok, X11 is included after Qt
... some classes ...
```

But then, some of the file go like this :

File3.hpp

```
#include "File1.hpp"
#include "File2.hpp"
```

So at some point during preprocessing, I presume it is transformed into

```
// #include "File1.hpp" ->
#include <SomeQtHeader.h>
#include <SomeX11Header.h> // X11 ends up included before Qt

// #include "File2.hpp" ->
#include <SomeOtherQtHeader.h>
#include <SomeX11Header.h>
```

I thought of using forward declaration but some structs and classes are not used as pointers, and a lot of them are even typedef'd so I end up forward declaring the original internal struct that the user is not supposed to utilize, and overall it's a big mess.

How I am supposed to deal with this problem efficiently, without abusing forward declaration and the use of pointers ?

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem, get rid of the order dependency in your includes. Maybe this requires abstracting out some common symbols into a shared library/resource.

Comment: The solution to this problem likely passes through fixing `debB.h` so it doesn't require a particular order of inclusions. For further assistance, explain in more detail what's in that header that leads to order dependency.

Comment: You have two choices: wrap dependencies with your code (this way both dependencies will never meet in translation unit) or provide details so we could help you resolve issue introduced by one of dependencies. For example I had problem with `fmt` library on macOS (some macro collision with function definition) and found nice workaround.

Comment: To give more details : depA in my case is Qt, and depB is X11. It seems like X11 redefines some symbols like None, which cause issue in qcoreevent.h. The Qt devs are aware and a comment says to include X11 related headers after all Qt header, however the project I'm trying to recompile mixes Qt and X11 headers everywhere.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik depB here is X11, sadly I am not sure I can fix it myself. It redefines symbols like None in the global namespace.

Comment: Use `#pragma once` on the top of every file to avoided duplication of header files. For more read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)

Comment: Xlib.h contains the following lines : #define Bool int, #define Status int, #define True 1, #define False 0. I guess it is intended as a C lib. Those are the symbols that causes issues.

Comment: @GHOSTHUNT that's not the problem. The problem is the order of includes. Nothing here is included more than once (the 2nd `#include <debB.h>` will do nothing).

Comment: this is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). X is dealing with order of includes (which isnt a good solution) while the actual problem is `Xlib.h` having some weird macros. Better explain your actual problem.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks, you're right. I'll clarify in the original post.

Comment: oh I just realized that you already have that information in the question, but it gets lost in the rest. I only understood what you are dealing with after reading your comments....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle with evil MACROs, you might wrap the X11 library into something like

```
// X11wrapper.h
#ifndef X11Wrapper_H
#define X11Wrapper_H

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#undef None
constexpr auto None = 0L;

#endif
```

and use that wrapper header instead of official one.

Comment: Thank you, this is the cleanest and fastest way of solving my issues ! I had to add other undef, too, I'll post them in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Jarod42 answer, here is my full wrapper with all the defines I had to undef and properly redefine, in the order they appeared in the compiler error log :

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_HPP
#define WRAPPER_HPP

#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#undef None
constexpr auto None = 0L;

#undef KeyPress
constexpr auto KeyPress = 2;

#undef KeyRelease
constexpr auto KeyRelease = 2;

#undef FocusIn
constexpr auto FocusIn = 9;

#undef FocusOut
constexpr auto FocusOut = 10;

#undef FontChange
constexpr auto FontChange = 255;

#undef Expose
constexpr auto Expose = 12;

#undef False
constexpr auto False = 0;

#undef True
constexpr auto True = 1;

#undef Status
typedef int Status;

#undef Unsorted
constexpr auto Unsorted = 0;

#undef Bool
typedef int Bool;

#endif // WRAPPER_HPP
```