# How to resolve a name conflict between function and macro name from header files of two different libraries?

Tags: c++

Compilation Error: macro and function with the same names leading to conflicts

I have an application that uses two libraries, lets say LibA and LibB. LibA has a macro whose name clashes with a function of LibB.
I'm not allowed to make any changes in the respective libraries.
The function is being consumed internally in LibB and hence I cannot make use of parentheses.

How do I resolve this conflict in my application space?
PS:I cannot use #undef

Comment: Seems all your ''cannot do this', 'cannot do that', have left you with a more or less impossible situation. The only thing you can do is never include header files from the two libraries in the same translation unit. You could file a bug report with the owner of LibA.

Comment: If you really "cannot use #undef", import the header defining the malicious macro in a separate file, write wrapper functions/classes to access the functionality and use those when interacting with the other library. But maybe reconsider using #undef.

Comment: You can include a header in a new namespace. If you do this, the macros persist in the "global" namespace while the functions are in the new namespace. If macro conflicts with another macro, you have to undef them.

Comment: @Klaus while this could be possible for header-only library up to a certain degree. It won't work if the header only contains a declaration, because the linker then won't find the corresponding definition.

Comment: @t.niese you can recompile your library with all functions in the namespace. Simply wrap the files in a new cpp file which opens the namespace, include the source file ( looks ugly but works ) and close the namespace. Typically no problem...

Comment: @Klaus I know that you can do that, but in the comment, you only talked about to  `include a header in a new namespace`. and the question says `I'm not allowed to make any changes in the respective libraries.`

Comment: @t.niese It will not change the library files. You can simply generate the wrapper files around, recompile, ready. If we really "can not undef" "can not wrap" and "must use macros" than we are not searching for a technical but a behavioral problem.

Comment: Similar to [how-to-solve-dependencies-inclusion-order-issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357978/how-to-solve-dependencies-inclusion-order-issues) with X11 and Qt.

Answer (score 0):

The most common instance of this problem is `#define min()`\ `#define max()` or similar functional macros in 3rd party library headers. Here comes a trick that works if macro in question is a function macro:

```
     (std::min)(a,b)
```

Parenthesis isolate macro name from the following argument list.

Now  there is another problem here: if 3rd party header is included *before* standard headers, there would be a conflict:

```
#define foo

// this declaration would be incorrect
void foo() { std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; }
```

No way around this unless you change order of inclusion or undefine offending macro. If that breaks functionality of library, creation of adapter that "hides" those headers within isolated module is required. Most common source of such are Xorg headers on linux, they redefine  quite a number of common names macro definitions (yes, no, cancel, min, max, etc.). This breaks such frameworks as Qt, OSG or similar where those are values of nested enums.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two libs named `LibA` and `LibB` and you want `LibA`'s macro not to expand the `LibB`'s function.

What I would do is creating a wrapper around `LibA` like this,

```cpp
/* WrappedLibA.h */

#pragma once

#include <LibB.h>
#include <LibA.h>
```

Now, instead including `LibA` include the new `WrappedLibA` in your application. One problem is that `LibB` is also included in placed where you only need `LibA`.

```cpp
/* my_file.cpp */

#include <WrappedLibA.h>

// you can use both LibA and LibB here
```

```cpp
/* my_another_file.cpp */

#include <LibB.h>

// you can use LibB here
```

#### How this works

As `WrappedLibA.h` includes `LibB.h` before `LibA.h`, the `LibB` will not *see* the macro from of `LibA`. And therefore, `LibB` will use the B's **function** inside of it while `LibA` and your code will use the A's **macro**.

As we have used header guards (`#pragma once` or `#ifndef W_LIB_A ...`) in the `WrappedLibA.h` the `LibB.h` will not included below this header again.